# How to itarate over a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to get each of the values for key symbols specifically(symbol and pricePrecision) of this Python dictionary.

```
response = {'timezone': 'UTC', 'serverTime': 1621287738195, 'futuresType': 'U_MARGINED', 'rateLimits': [{'rateLimitType': 'REQUEST_WEIGHT', 'interval': 'MINUTE', 'intervalNum': 1, 'limit': 2400}, {'rateLimitType': 'ORDERS', 'interval': 'MINUTE', 'intervalNum': 1, 'limit': 1200}, {'rateLimitType': 'ORDERS', 'interval': 'SECOND', 'intervalNum': 10, 'limit': 300}], 'exchangeFilters': [], 'assets': [{'asset': 'USDT', 'marginAvailable': True, 'autoAssetExchange': '-10000'}, {'asset': 'BNB', 'marginAvailable': False, 'autoAssetExchange': '0'}, {'asset': 'BUSD', 'marginAvailable': True, 'autoAssetExchange': '-10000'}, {'asset': 'BTC', 'marginAvailable': True, 'autoAssetExchange': '-0.00100000'}], 'symbols': [{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'pair': 'BTCUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'BTC', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 2, 'quantityPrecision': 3, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '556.72', 'maxPrice': '1000000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.01'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'pair': 'ETHUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'ETH', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 2, 'quantityPrecision': 3, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '39.86', 'maxPrice': '100000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.01'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '10000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '10000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']}, {'symbol': 'BCHUSDT', 'pair': 'BCHUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'BCH', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 2, 'quantityPrecision': 3, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '13.93', 'maxPrice': '100000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.01'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '10000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']}, {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'pair': 'XRPUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'XRP', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 4, 'quantityPrecision': 1, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '0.0143', 'maxPrice': '100000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.0001'}, {'stepSize': '0.1', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000000', 'minQty': '0.1'}, {'stepSize': '0.1', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000000', 'minQty': '0.1'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']}]}
```

So far I have only been able to obtain the value of one symbol at a time with all the values through this code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def subindex(d, ks):

    return dict(zip(ks, itemgetter(*ks)(d)))

response = response 

subindex(response, ['symbols'])
print(response['symbols'][3])
```

Is there a way to get each of the symbols from the symbols key without having to do it individually?

Regards,

Orlando Gautier

Comment: The answer did not answer my question, the suggested solutions work with a dictionary that is not nested, in my case I have that dictionary nested with a symbols key that has symbol as one of its values, and this symbol that I need to access.

Regards,

Oelando Gautier

Comment: Please provide the _minimal_ reproducible example.

Comment: With this code:
 
from operator import itemgetter
def subindex(d, ks):
    return dict(zip(ks, itemgetter(*ks)(d)))
response = response 
subindex(response, ['symbols'])
print(response['symbols'][1])

I can get:
{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'pair': 'ETHUSDT','maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'ETH', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 
'pricePrecision': 2,.....and so on.....'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']}]}

There are 116 symbol, I just need symbol and pricePrecision. It is possible to get each of the symbols separately?

Answer (score 0):

I fairly certain that ultimately [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) is your answer.

If it is not, then you need to clarify exactly what output you expect.

At the moment given:

```
response = {
    'timezone': 'UTC',
    'serverTime': 1621287738195,
    'futuresType': 'U_MARGINED',
    'rateLimits': [
        {'rateLimitType': 'REQUEST_WEIGHT', 'interval': 'MINUTE', 'intervalNum': 1, 'limit': 2400},
        {'rateLimitType': 'ORDERS', 'interval': 'MINUTE', 'intervalNum': 1, 'limit': 1200},
        {'rateLimitType': 'ORDERS', 'interval': 'SECOND', 'intervalNum': 10, 'limit': 300}
    ],
    'exchangeFilters': [],
    'assets': [
        {'asset': 'USDT', 'marginAvailable': True, 'autoAssetExchange': '-10000'},
        {'asset': 'BNB', 'marginAvailable': False, 'autoAssetExchange': '0'},
        {'asset': 'BUSD', 'marginAvailable': True, 'autoAssetExchange': '-10000'},
        {'asset': 'BTC', 'marginAvailable': True, 'autoAssetExchange': '-0.00100000'}
    ],
    'symbols': [
        {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'pair': 'BTCUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'BTC', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 2, 'quantityPrecision': 3, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '556.72', 'maxPrice': '1000000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.01'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']},
        {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'pair': 'ETHUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'ETH', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 2, 'quantityPrecision': 3, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '39.86', 'maxPrice': '100000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.01'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '10000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '10000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']},
        {'symbol': 'BCHUSDT', 'pair': 'BCHUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'BCH', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 2, 'quantityPrecision': 3, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '13.93', 'maxPrice': '100000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.01'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '10000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'stepSize': '0.001', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000', 'minQty': '0.001'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']},
        {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'pair': 'XRPUSDT', 'contractType': 'PERPETUAL', 'deliveryDate': 4133404800000, 'onboardDate': 1569398400000, 'status': 'TRADING', 'maintMarginPercent': '2.5000', 'requiredMarginPercent': '5.0000', 'baseAsset': 'XRP', 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'marginAsset': 'USDT', 'pricePrecision': 4, 'quantityPrecision': 1, 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quotePrecision': 8, 'underlyingType': 'COIN', 'underlyingSubType': [], 'settlePlan': 0, 'triggerProtect': '0.0500', 'filters': [{'minPrice': '0.0143', 'maxPrice': '100000', 'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'tickSize': '0.0001'}, {'stepSize': '0.1', 'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000000', 'minQty': '0.1'}, {'stepSize': '0.1', 'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'maxQty': '1000000', 'minQty': '0.1'}, {'limit': 200, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS'}, {'limit': 10, 'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS'}, {'notional': '5', 'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL'}, {'multiplierDown': '0.8500', 'multiplierUp': '1.1500', 'multiplierDecimal': '4', 'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE'}], 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'MARKET', 'STOP', 'STOP_MARKET', 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET', 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET'], 'timeInForce': ['GTC', 'IOC', 'FOK', 'GTX']}
    ]
}
```

You can get each symbol and price via:

```
for symbol in response["symbols"]:
    print(symbol["symbol"], symbol["pricePrecision"])
```

alternatively if you want to store that in a list it might be:

```
all_symbols = [(symbol["symbol"], symbol["pricePrecision"]) for symbol in response["symbols"]]
for symbol in all_symbols:
    print(symbol[0], symbol[1])
```

If either of these helps, then let me know in a comment so we can close this as a dupe.

If what you are looking for is some sort of method to give you the price for a specific symbol, then this might help:

```
def getPrice(response, symbol_id):
    matches = [s for s in response["symbols"] if s["symbol"] == symbol_id]
    if not matches:
        return None
    return matches[0].get("pricePrecision")

print(getPrice(response, "ETHUSDT"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, everything you have indicated is specifically what I needed.

Comment: If you now feel that this is potentially a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops then you can likely close this via the "close" link above then indicating it is a dupe. Alternatively you can delete the question.